# Password Strength checker plugin issue

Tags: jquery

**[I am following this JQuery script to check password strength](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Password-Strength-Checker-and-Indicator-Password-Strength.html)**.

**[Here is the online demo for this.](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Password-Strength-Checker-and-Indicator-Password-Strength/)**

This script is missing special character check. I did below work to add the special char check in password_strength_lightweight file

1. Variable Declaration `var specialChar = new RegExp('[\W]');`
2. Message string. `<li data-criterion="SpecialCharCase" class="invalid">At least <strong>one special character</strong></li> \`
3. JQuery to check if atleast one special char exists. `var SpecialCharCase = password.match(specialChar) ? 1 : 0;`
4. Inform plugin to mark valid or invalid. `that._update_info('SpecialCharCase', SpecialCharCase);`

**Problem**
It always shows Special char condition invalid. Am I missing anything? Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Try `var specialChar = /\W/;` or `var specialChar = new RegExp('[\\W]')`.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Please do not update your existing posts.